# Android : How to Get Namespace of a Renamed Package Name For Facebook?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk

I have an `Android` app and its package name is `com.domain.myapp`. During the development, I have to change it to something else due to some reasons and I changed it to `com.domain.myappandroid`.

Now, I have to integrate `Facebook SDK` for `Android` and it asks me to add the package name and the class name of my `Activity`. My `Activity` is named `GameActivity` and it is in `com.domain.myapp.activities`, the package name didn't change to `com.domain.myappandroid.activities` after changing my app package name.

I know that the package name is `com.domain.myappandroid` but I am not sure if I should use `com.domain.myapp.activities.GameActivity` or `com.domain.myappandroid.activities.GameActivity`. I tried both and I don't know if it is working or not since the dashboard says **0 installs for Android**.

Please help, thanks!

Note:
I am using using `Facebook Android SDK v3.0.2` and I can't verify if it is reporting the app installs properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the package name of your app i.e. com.domain.appandroid. It will work fine.

Comment: So on `Class Name`, I will use `com.domain.myappandroid.activities.GameActivity`? Thanks!

Comment: In class you will use the package name which is in the first line of the class. According to me class name doesn't matter in the facebook class. It will work in both cases.

Comment: Thanks! My problem here is that I can't verify if the app install is being reported because I am having 0 installs. I can't make it work.

Comment: you will get the no. of daily users in the insights of app.

Answer (score 0):

actually you should use com.domain.myapp，  the class name have nothing to do with the Facebook SDK function but callback to game site ，    it means wether classname you used， the Facebook function will worked well，  but if you use the com.domain.myappandroid， players click the message that send by their friends，  the game will not launched。。。。 so  ~  use com.domain.myapp~  i just have the same case~ and i worked very well by this way！